# Get Data from api in redux-saga reactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to fetch data from API In my redux-saga but I'm getting following error from here `const {body: {data}} =yield getData()` in my redux-saga:

`cannot read property body of udefined`

Here is my API Function:

```
    export function* getData() {
    yield agent
        .get(
            "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=xxx"
        )
        .then((res) => {
            getCurrencies(res.body.data);
            console.log('--------res.body.data', res.body.data);
            setPageCount();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

`.then` is returning the data itself,So it is not undefined

Here is my redux-saga itself:

```
    function* loadDataAsync() {
  console.log("SAGAS WORKS");
    yield delay(5000);
  try {
    const {body: {data}} =yield getData()
    console.log(data)
    yield put({type:"LOAD_DATA_ASYNC_SUCCESS"});
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    yield put({type:"LOAD_DATA_ASYNC_ERROR"})
  }
}

export function* watchLoadDataAsync() {
  yield takeLatest("LOAD_DATA_ASYNC", loadDataAsync);
}
```

Any solutions please?

Comment: "but I'm getting following error: cannot define data of undefined" - Where? What is the stacktrace at the point of the error? What are the values of the variables at that point?

Comment: The error I'm getting is from here `const {body: {data}} =yield getData()`

Comment: And what is the result of `yield getData()`? The `.then(...)` doesn't return anything, so probably undefined?

Comment: .then returns the data itself I checked it and it is not undefined

Comment: Try removing `.then` and `.catch` for `getData` api call and change it to `yield call(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `call` to get the data back from your **asynchronous action**

```
function* loadDataAsync() {
  console.log("SAGAS WORKS");
    yield delay(5000);
  try {
    const {body: {}} = yield call(agent.get, "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=xxx");
    console.log(body.data);
    // Call your other functions here
    getCurrencies(body.data);
    setPageCount();

    yield put({type:"LOAD_DATA_ASYNC_SUCCESS"});
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    yield put({type:"LOAD_DATA_ASYNC_ERROR"})
  }
}
```

For more information check out the official docs for [call](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But the problem in ur code is that I can not access `data`

Comment: Line 14:19:  'data' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: I guess it's `body.data`. My bad. Updated my answer 